# How to fix git commit on windows: "Waiting ... to close ... file: ... vim.exe: C:/Program: No such file or directory"

Tags: windows, git, vim

Does anyone know how to fix this error?  Everything worked fine a few days ago in this same repository.  Now that I'm trying to commit new changes, I get this error that I cannot fix.  As far as I know, nothing has changed except for some Windows updates from patch Tuesday.

```
$ git commit
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/vim.exe: C:/Program: No such file or directory
error: There was a problem with the editor 'C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/vim.exe'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.

$ git config --global core.editor
C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/vim.exe
```

I've upgraded git for windows to the latest, but that didn't help. The error doesn't make any sense; vim runs fine.  It says that git is waiting for vim to close "C:/Program", but that sounds like git passed vim a full path but forgot to escape the space.  How could that happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to fix quotes in your `.gitconfig`:

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/vim.exe'"
```

Comment: My first sentence is not enough?

Comment: Hmm. Okay, i guess.  But, how did it get broken?  It worked one day and not the next. I don't remember changing it.